# Why IE 11 doesn't apply SVG styles with external CSS?

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, d3.js, svg

I draw `SVG` path inside the template. It looks good for Chrome, Firefox and Edge, but IE 11 doesn't display my path. When I start using inline attributes it works fine for IE 11, but it doesn't look elegantly. I want to keep my code concise.

IE 11 doesn't display my `path` if I use the following template and external CSS.

```
<svg:g>
    <svg:path [ngClass]="path.pathType === solid 
            ? 'solid-path'
            : 'dotted-path'" 
            [attr.d]="pathValue">
    </svg:path>
</svg:g>
```

External CSS:

```
.solid-path {
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: transparent;
}

.dotted-path {
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-dasharray: 3, 3;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: transparent;
}
```

Everything works fine if I use the following template with inline attributes.

```
<svg:g>
   <svg:path 
      stroke="blue"
      fill="transparent"
      [attr.d]="pathValue"
      [attr.stroke-dasharray]="path.pathType !== solid ? 3 : 0">
   </svg:path>
</svg:g>
```

How can I make IE 11 use the styles from external `CSS` instead of inline attributes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you linking to the external CSS?

Comment: These styles is located at `path.component.scss`. I have separate `common.scss` file that contains all imports from all app components. I added the import of `path.component.scss` to this common file. Webpack uses it for applying styles for the whole application.

Comment: can you post the Enough code (include the code in the .ts file) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).